# QGIS: use graph builder to classify multiple images at once

Tags: qgis, land-classification

I am classifying subsets (Sentinel 1, Sentinel 2, NDVI, and Landsat 8 data) in order to see which image as the highest accruacy. These classifications are taking several days for each of the images. Is it possible to use QGIS graph builder to classify the images simultaneously?